# Google Earth Engine: error when creating function to calculate total monthly rainfall when data missing for specific months in multi-year sequence

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have developed a GEE script to calculate total monthly rainfall by district based on CHIRPS daily data. In the below snippet I am selecting the timeframe for analysis as Jan 2021 to October 2023. However, as I have set the month variable as 1-12, it gives me an error because there is no data yet for November and December 2023.

The error is as follows:

```
ImageCollection (Error)
Element.copyProperties: The source parameter is required.
```

The script works fine if setting the data range up until Dec 2022 because data is available for every month until then. However, I would like to run the code up to the most recent month of data availability (currently October 2023). Is there a way of forcing the code to ignore months with no data when iterating through the months list?

Please see the snippet with the issue below and a full link to the code here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/e4167895ee5b5078d7da940170b5e4c1.

```
//filter CHIRPS collection by time period of interest - adjust time period and years variable as necessary
var chirps = ee.ImageCollection('UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2021-01-01', '2023-10-31')) //adjust time period
                  .sort('system:time_start');
var precipitation = chirps.select('precipitation');
var years = ee.List.sequence(2021, 2023); //adjust years
var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12); // adjust months


//function to iterate through each year (or time period within year) in sequence and calculate total monthly rainfall

var lt_precip = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      years.map(function (y) {
        return months.map(function (m) {
          var collection = precipitation.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'));
          return collection
                    .sum()
                    .set('year', y)
                    .set('month', m)
                    .copyProperties(collection.first(),['system:time_start'])
          });
      }).flatten());
print("lt_precip",lt_precip);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your problem by adding an if condition using `ee.Algorithms.If` as follows:

```
var lt_precip = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function (y) {
    return months.map(function (m) {
      var collection = precipitation.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'));
      var collectionExists = collection.size().gt(0)
      var result = ee.Algorithms.If({
        condition: collectionExists,
        trueCase: collection
          .sum()
          .set('year', y)
          .set('month', m)
          .copyProperties(collection.first(),['system:time_start']),
        falseCase: ee.Image()
      })
      return result
    });
  }).flatten());
print("lt_precip",lt_precip);
```

That way, if no collection exists, you won't be using `copyProperties` on an empty object.

I used `ee.Image()` as a placeholder arbitrarily but you can replace it with anything as long as it's compatible. For example, you may want to populate your empty image with dummy properties, like:

```
ee.Image().set('year', y).set('month', m)
```